# Differentiating between when a user calls a method and when a computer calls a method

Tags: python-3.x, class

I'm having trouble with figuring out how to know when a user calls a class method and when the method is called within my own code.

```
class animal:
    def lower_stats(self):
        if user_called==True:
            return("You monster")
        else:
            self.hunger-=10
    def other_code(self):
        ...
        self.lower_stats()
```

How can I make it to where when a user calls `.lower_stats()` it returns `"You monster"`, but when `.other_code()` executes `.lower_stats()`, 10 will be subtracted from `self.hunger`?

Answer (score 0):

The methode itself can not know whether it got called by a code or from elsewhere.
It basically gets always called as a codeblock no distinctions made.

The only way to like get similar behaviour is making the methods private by annotating it with two double underscores at the start of the methode name.
And writing a public one that does something when a user calls it.

[Geeks For Geeks Private Methodes Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/private-methods-in-python/)

Tho that won't really stop people from calling the private function cause in python  there are no real private methodes.

Another way would be having some kind of logic inside the function to authorize the call to the function.

Tho that can be bypassed...